# How to create 2d ListPlot with distinct colors?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, date-and-time

I have a data set of type (x,y,E), where E can assume 4 distinct configurations (0,0), (1,0), (0,1) or (1,1). I want to create a 2D plot using ListPlot considering the rules:

1. If E=(0,0), then print red
2. If E=(1,0), then print blue
3. If E=(0,1), then print green
4. If E=(1,1), then print black
   the respective coordinate (x,y). See illustrative Figure below

[image]

```
data=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ9L8.png"], "Byte"]]]]
```

The code doesn't work

```
ListPlot[Partition[data[[All ;; 2]], 2, 1], 
 PlotStyle -> (Rest[
     data[[All, -1]]] /. {{0, 1} -> Green, {1, 0} -> Blue, {0, 0} -> 
      Red, {1, 1} -> Black})]
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
colorRule = Association[{{0, 0} -> Red, {1, 0} -> Blue, {0, 1} -> 
     Green, {1, 1} -> Black}];
```

Wrap each xy pair with `List` and map `colorRule` on the last column to get a list of colors to be used as `PlotStyle` option setting:

```
colors = (colorRule /@ data[[All, -1]]);

ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, ;; 2]], 
 PlotStyle -> colors, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `Style` to assign the desired colors to the xy pairs::

```
styledData = Style[{#, #2}, colorRule @ #3] & @@@ data;

ListPlot[styledData, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Comment: A much faster version might be `Graphics[Point[data[[All, ;; 2]], VertexColors -> colors], 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to providing colors for each point individually as in kglr's answer, you can also group the elements by the last element before plotting. This can be done in several different ways. Here's one example:

```
groups = GroupBy[data, Last][[All, All, ;; 2]];
ListPlot[{
  groups[{0, 1}],
  groups[{1, 0}],
  groups[{0, 0}],
  groups[{1, 1}]
  },
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue, Red, Black},
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]
 ]
```

[image: List plot]